# Distinct values from an ARRAY column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using PostgreSQL's ARRAY to store tags for images.

How can I write an ORM query in SQLAlchemy, which returns the set of all tags found in the table, for the following model:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'images'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    tags = Column(ARRAY(Unicode))
```

I guess I need to use a lateral join, but I do not know how to do it using SQLAlchemy's ORM syntax.

PG version: 9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `func.unnest`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(func.unnest(Image.tags)).distinct().all()
```

`distinct()` will make the result a set and `unnest` will split the arrays into separate rows (like the postgresql function `unnest`).

Comment: So you are saying that there is no need for lateral here?

Comment: Yes, just like you can do `SELECT DISTINCT unnest(tags) FROM images` in plain postgresql

Comment: So if I want a real Python set, I need to do a `{e[0] for e in result}` afterwards, but this will be quite performant, wouldn't it? Or is there anything in SQLAlchemy / Postgres which would do this to me?

Comment: @zsero if you want a python `set` object, you would have to do that, yes. sqlalchemy cannot do that for you

Comment: even for a list, I'd need to do something with those 1 item sub-tuples, wouldn't I?

Comment: If you want a plain list of strings you would do a list comprehension instead of a set comprehension, e.g. `[e[0] for e in result]`